# GUI for a Python based water modeling software

Tags: python, gui

My professor has developed the back-end of her Python-based water modeling software , which is being run on the university's linux server. She was talking about how she would appreciate it if someone would help her to develop the GUI, so I signed up for it. I have some knowledge using PyQt and Flask, and I have dabbled with a bunch of JS libraries. I will be meeting with her tomorrow to get an idea of how the software works, and we will be brainstorming and trying to come up with a plan on how to approach the GUI.

I don't want to meet with her empty handed. I'd like to be prepared with some solutions and ideas to share with her. Can someone help me come up with some ideas and/or questions to ask?

The questions I have so far: 
Will it be a web application, server based, or desktop based software?
Would you consider creating APIs and then using them in JavaScript to develop the front-end? (Since we might be integrating geo-spacial visualizations and there's some powerful libraries in JS)

Any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: Q: is usage fully interactive, or does a model run take longer, like say, 3 weeks?

Comment: How does she want to present the data? Tabular? Charts? Is the GUI getting it in real-time, or from a database, or must it handle both?

Comment: Does she want to raise any alarms if certain critical values arise?